# Usage of 'in in' in a sentence

Tags: grammar, punctuation

Is punctuation required between the repeated in's?

> "...users who are still active yet haven't logged **in in** more than
>   x days..."

Comment: Punctuation is unnecessary here. The sentence is valid and meaningful, despite the awkward repetition.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that sentence is OK, as is. It just looks *odd*.  Punctuation would only make it look odder.

On the other hand, when I am writing and run into circumstances like that, I try my best to find another way around the double-word.

This is how I would handle this one:

> "...users who are still active yet haven't logged in **for** more than
>   x days..."

Comment: The suggestion is a natural one but equivocal over additional senses meaning "users who are still active yet haven't remained logged in for more than x days" or even "users who are still active yet haven't logged in for a cumulative total of of more than x days".  I would prefer "...users who are still active (or active users) and who have gone x consecutive days without logging in..."

Comment: @Merk, it's going to vary depending upon circumstances, as you point out.  I was addressing the questioner's immediate concern, not trying to digress over the entire problem space.

Comment: I actually had changed the sentence to read: "...users who are still active yet haven't logged in for more than x days..." as it sounded better.  I was just curious as to whether it was technically correct or not.

Comment: Another rewording option would be "users who .. haven't logged **on** in more than x days..."